# How handle Log File in in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, logfiles, logfile, log-files

I don't know how to handle log file in selenium webdriver using java .. 
i wanna perform following task in log file :
 - store label of each link of website page in log file
 - Read that stored label one by one

is it possible in selenium ...?

Comment: This isn't anything to do with Selenium. Selenium automates browsers. It doesn't create log files for you. Have a search. It is very easy to see how you can write to a log file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758685/how-to-write-logs-in-text-file-when-using-java-util-logging-logger]

Comment: If you want to read each link's label and store it, you can use Hashmap or Arraylist for the same. But if you want to print them to a log file, you can use the best log tool available [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)