# How to collect LogCat messages in an Android application

Tags: android, logcat

I have an application and I'd like to collect the *LogCat* messages of a specified level and tag.

Can I somehow get the accumulated messages at some point? I don't want to collect the messages one by one, it should be the sum of them like when I use adb to read the actual log. Is this possible?

Comment: please take a look at my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file

Comment: Your answer seems promising, especially *extractLogToFile*. However, when I use on a 2.3 phone with the following line: "logcat -d -v MyTAG:v *:S"*, I always get a -1 in *reader.read()*. What should I set?

Comment: That probably means your filtering on logcat is excluding all rows.  Try removing the filtering and see if you get something.

Comment: I didn't have the required permission. After I added it, it worked well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: Note that in Android 4 you will only see the log messages that were written by your own app unless you have root access.

```
public static String getLog(Context c) {
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line);
            log.append("\n");
        }

       return log.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A very important thing: reading the log requires a permission! Use this in your manifest:   **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />**

Comment: You do not need this permission to collect your own apps logs in Api 16 up. See this post by hackbod (android software engineer). https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/6U4A5irWang/AvZsrTdfICIJ

Comment: Thanks for the information. I use my log collector starting from API level 10.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just write them to a file instead?  LogCat is really for real-time logs.  There are lots of good quality logging packages that can log to a file if that's what you want to do.

Just as an example:

[How to write logs in text file when using java.util.logging.Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758685/how-to-write-logs-in-text-file-when-using-java-util-logging-logger)