# Java Logging to files using pattern

Tags: java, logging

I wrote a CXF SOAP client and would like to create numbered log files for each run.

I have tried configuring FileHandler using "logging.properties" file. I have this line there:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler
.level= INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = campaignStatusCXF%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
# Limit the message that are printed on the console to WARNING and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

But it does not work just by itself. I had to add FileHandler in the code:

System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "/logging.properties");
LOG = Logger.getLogger(BulkEmailDownloader.class.getName());

```
try {
    FileHandler logFile;
    logFile = new FileHandler("campaignStatus.log");
    logFile.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    LOG.addHandler(logFile);
} catch (SecurityException e1) {            
} catch (IOException e2) {          
}
```

The problem with this approach is - it simply rewrites the log all the time.

I read numerous examples and answers, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15758768/1515058), but could not find the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the the LogManager configuration runs before your code is executed.  This means you have to do one of the following:

1. Set the 'java.util.logging.config.file' system property in your startup script.
2. Call [LogManager.readConfiguration()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration%28%29) after you set the system property in your code.
3. Use [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [LogManager.readConfiguration(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration%28java.io.InputStream%29) to load your properties file.

Also, your example code needs to include a file pattern:

```
new FileHandler("campaignStatus%g.log");
```