# Java single log file

Tags: java

I'm writing a log file in my Java program using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758685/how-to-write-logs-in-text-file-when-using-java-util-logging-logger)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
FileHandler fh;  

try {  

    // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
    fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");  
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
    fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

    // the following statement is used to log any messages  
    logger.info("My first log");  

    } catch (SecurityException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

    logger.info("Hi How r u?");  

}
```

My problem is that i'm getting a multiple log files

Comment: You mean your log file gets overwritten for every new programm execution?

Comment: what do you mean by multiple log files.  Can you give an example?  Is this from one run that yhou get multiples or from several runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code as below

```
fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log", true);
```

This will not create multiple files and will append to the same file.

Comment: I had the same issue, it is due to new object creation of FileHandler which happens to create new log files everytime the application is run.