# Redirecting output stream of JSch exec channel to a file using setOutputStream does not work

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using JSch exec channel to login to multiple servers and run few commands. Then I need to capture the output and store it in a file called `log`. For some odd reason, the file remains blank after executing.

```
try (OutputStream log = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath))) {
    ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
    lists.add("hostname");
    lists.add("df -l");
    String host ="localhost";

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    try {
        String user = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(getProperties());
        session.setTimeout(20 * 1000);
        System.out.println(session.getTimeout());
        session.connect();
        if (session.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println(host + " Session Established ");
        }

        for (String elem : lists) {
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.setOutputStream(log);

            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(elem);

            channel.setInputStream(null);

            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect();

            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    if (in.available() > 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                }
            }
            channel.disconnect();
        }

        session.disconnect();
```

The program displays the output via the IDE console, but the output file gets created but it remains blank.

Then I set the `system.setOut` to a file, this prevented the console from displaying anymore more data but the `output.txt` file remains blank.

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"))));
```

Comment: Why not use a logging library? It would probably be easier...

Comment: Do you have an example or a link to use as reference?

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758685/how-to-write-logs-in-text-file-when-using-java-util-logging-logger - but if you google "java log to file example" I'm sure you will find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `getInputStream` overrides the `setOutputStream` call.

See how these methods are implemented in JSch (both end up calling `io.setOutputStream`):

```
public void setOutputStream(OutputStream out){
  io.setOutputStream(out, false);
}

public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
  int max_input_buffer_size = 32*1024;
  try {
    max_input_buffer_size =
      Integer.parseInt(getSession().getConfig("max_input_buffer_size"));
  }
  catch(Exception e){}
  PipedInputStream in =
    new MyPipedInputStream(
                           32*1024,  // this value should be customizable.
                           max_input_buffer_size
                           );
  boolean resizable = 32*1024<max_input_buffer_size;
  io.setOutputStream(new PassiveOutputStream(in, resizable), false);
  return in;
}
```

I assume you actually do not need that output reading block based on `InputStream in`. Just remove it and the log file writing should start working.

---

Side note: The output stream will be closed by default with the channel. As you reuse the same stream for multiple channels, you should prevent that.

Use an override of the `setOutputStream` with `dontclose` argument:

```
public void setOutputStream(OutputStream out, boolean dontclose)
```

like this:

```
channel.setOutputStream(log, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It truly put things into prospective.