# java.io.IOException when declaring path to log file

Tags: java

I'm trying to log to a file in Java, so I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758685/how-to-write-logs-in-text-file-when-using-java-util-logging-logger/15758768#15758768) and wrote the following code:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( QualityGatesProvider.class.getName() );
//some other code
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("/Users/me/.jenkins/myLogs");
log.addHandler(fh);
```

However, on the line `FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("/Users/me/.jenkins/myLogs");`, I get this:

```
unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Any idea what could be wrong with the code?

Comment: Looks like this code is not inside a block. You cannot just have random code in a `class`. You are allowed `static` variable declarations and instance variables declarations only. Also note that while your `log` is `static` your `fh` is not so if this were to work, you would be adding a `FileHandler` every time you create an instance of the `class` in question.

Comment: Now the entire question is changed. So, which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.io.IOException is a [checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation). Therefore, any line that could throw it must be either:

.-Included in a try-catch block that captures it.

```
try{
        ...

        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("/Users/me/.jenkins/myLogs");
        ...

    } catch (java.io.IOException e){
        //handle exception
    }
```

.-Included in a method that throws it explicitly.

```
void myMethod() throws java.io.IOException{
...
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("/Users/me/.jenkins/myLogs");
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write this code inside a block:

```
log.addHandler(fh);
```

It cannot be directly placed in the body of a `class` along with other class member declarations.

Put it inside a method like this:

```
public void foo() {
    log.addHandler(fh); // this will still give a compilation error
}
```

To solve the compilation error,

Declare the method to throw the exception or handle it right inside the method.

```
public void foo() throws Exception{
    log.addHandler(fh);
}
```

OR

```
public void foo() {
    try{
        log.addHandler(fh);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printstacktrace();
        // OR handle exception here
    }
}
```

---

Hope this helps!