# Can't see console's outputs from client as they gets overriden by logs from server

Tags: java, logging

I've been struggling learning *Message Driven Beans* lately with some *JMS* providers, mainly under *Wildfly* / *JBoss* container.

As the remote client sending some messages to queue living in container/server, I've never got a chance to see what the remote client (JavaSE) suppose to output, this happens in the case of remote client in term of *JMS* or *EJB* invocation from client. For etc. all those *`System.out.println()`* , as the console output's filled with the logs from server:

> HOTSWAP AGENT: 22:03:05.499 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.HotswapAgent) -
>   Loading Hotswap agent {1.1.0-SNAPSHOT} - unlimited runtime class
>   redefinition. HOTSWAP AGENT: 22:03:07.057 INFO
>   (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Discovered plugins:
>   [Hotswapper, WatchResources, AnonymousClassPatch, ClassInitPlugin,
>   Hibernate, Hibernate3JPA, Hibernate3, Spring, Jersey1, Jersey2, Jetty,
>   Tomcat, ZK, Logback, Log4j2, MyFaces, Mojarra, Seam, ELResolver,
>   WildFlyELResolver, OsgiEquinox, Owb, Proxy, WebObjects, Weld,
>   JBossModules, ResteasyRegistry, Deltaspike, JavaBeans, GlassFish]
>   22:03:11,528 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version
>   1.3.0.Final 22:03:13,882 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.0.Final 22:03:14,467 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service
>   thread 1-4) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" starting
>   22:03:25,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding
>   (management-http) .... ....

No more outputs from the client anymore, *Ctrl+F* won't work, since they're completely gone.

How to configure things in this case?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and your word-layout/grammar is incomprehensible. Please edit your question and take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok thanks sorry, I'm not good in English, but I'll improve my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try logging to a file isntead of to the console instead. Take a look at  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15758768/7756856) for an example.

Comment: Hey that  looks good, but let me read it first, hopefully it's related to my case.

Comment: Perhaps some portion of the output cut in the console. Thanks.