# Execute sql file using jdbc and write log to a file instead of std output or print only errors

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wrote a simple program to execute a particularly large SQL file on a mysql database . The program is working fine, but because the SQL has large amount of data , the log generated is very large and unreadable. 
Is there some way to make jdbc print only errors or make it write the log into a file .

Comment: In catch() block, you can create if conditions and accordingly you can insert those logs wherever you want

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758685/how-to-write-logs-in-text-file-when-using-java-util-logging-logger

Comment: How do you generate the log currently? Normally, you use a logging framework for this kind of stuff, which allows you to simply configure which logging messages go where.

Comment: are you using log4j?

Comment: @sForSujit  no I am not using log4j or anyother logger . All logs are written to console .

Answer (score 2):

You can use any Logger, like Log4j and log in Catch statement:

**Steps to follow:**

          Download latest log4j distribution.
          Add log4j’s jar library into your program’s classpath.
          Create log4j’s configuration.
          Initialize log4j with the configuration.
          Create a logger.
          Put logging statements into your code.

```
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

try {
      // Your risky code goes between these curly braces!!!
 }
 catch(Exception ex) {
    // Log your errors here
       logger.info("This is my first log4j's statement");

}
 finally {
      // Your must-always-be-executed code goes between these 
     // curly braces. Like closing database connection.
  }
```

`

Ref:http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-configure-log4j-as-logging-mechanism-in-java

Comment: Ya I think log4j is the way to go . I'll give it a try .

Comment: @born let me know you exact need so that i can modify code accordingly , meanwhile this will give you a fair idea about logging SQL errors

Comment: Sorry for replying late . Followed your Idea . Got it working thanks . @mohit sharma