# How to disable Vert.x' default console output?

Tags: vert.x, java.util.logging

I'm using **Vert.x 3.8.4 (JavaScript)** to write a command line application. The output to the console should be limited to what the application itself creates. However, when using the **io.vertx.core.Launcher** to run the application script, it automatically prints the following lines at start:

> Dec 28, 2019 12:04:21 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer
>   INFO: Succeeded in deploying verticle

How can I disable/suppress this output?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6126104/1697566

The respective JavaScript snippet to disable the default console logging looks like this:

```js
var hndlrs0,lgr0=java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("");
if (lgr0 && (hndlrs0=lgr0.getHandlers()).length) lgr0.removeHandler(hndlrs0[0]);
```